# HTML Calendar: Bottom image being displayed on the right not at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have a HTML page that is supposed to display a calendar.** There is an image meant to be displayed above the calendar & one below. But the one **below(id=bottomCell)** gets displayed incorrectly(on the right NOT below).

Can you assist me by telling me how to get the bottom picture to be in the correct position?

Please find my html & png's here http://www.mediafire.com/?bcddcen1tdc2urr so you can view what goes wrong with the images & how its displayed

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/homepage.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dropDownMenu.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        <!--

        html, body, div, form, fieldset, legend, label, img {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  }  table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; }  th, td {  text-align: center;  }  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td, caption { font-weight:normal; }  img { border: 0; } 

        a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

        #container {position: relative;  background-color: #BCC5C5; }
        #calendar { float: left; background-color: #BCC5C5; width: 435px; }
        #calendar th { position: relative; }
        #topCell  {}
        #bottomCell { }
        #leftButton  { float: left; position: relative; 
        #rightButton { float: left; position: relative; }

        -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <img id="topCell" src="../Images/topTableCell.png" alt="" width="500px" height="50px"/>
        <div id="container">
            <a id="leftButton" ><img src="../Images/leftButton.png" height="30px" width="30px" alt=""/></a>
            <table id="calendar">
                <th colspan=7> abcd </th>
                <tr> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>abcd</td> </tr>
            </table>
            <a id="rightButton" ><img src="../Images/rightButton.png" height="30px" width="30px" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <img id="bottomCell" src="../Images/bottomTableCell.png" alt="" width="500px" height="30px"/>
    </div>

</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mack

In your `container` div there are three floating elements & you didn't clear it . so, first clear it

```
#container {position: relative;  background-color: #BCC5C5;  overflow:hidden; width:500px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the bottom image, I would try making it display block:

```
#bottomCell {display:block;}
```

That will override the default `inline-block` which may be resulting in the apparent wrapping behaviour.